# I am unable to import beautifulsoup in python3

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

when I run `pip install BeautifulSoup4` in command line , it shows output such that

> Requirement already satisfied: BeautifulSoup4 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (4.5.1)

Beautiful soup is installed in `python2.7` not in `python 3.5`

I even copied `bs4` and `BeautifulSoup4` folder from `python 2.7/dist-packages` to `python3.5/distutils/` still import `BeautifulSoup4` showing error that is `No module named 'Beautiful Soup' found`

while running `Beutifulsoup4` in `python2.7` , I didn't get relevant output as I was excepting to get as i was parsing a HTML webpage .

please help me how to install `bs4` in `python3.5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install BeautifulSoup4 using following command:

`pip3 install BeautifulSoup4`

If it doesn't work then try,

`python3 -m pip install BeautifulSoup4`

In the worst case, None of the above work, try the following command

`apt-get install python3-bs4`

or, for the non-root user.

`sudo apt-get install python3-bs4`

Comment: /usr/bin/python3: No module named pip

Comment: okay. I think that might be an issue related to drivers, @TanujSharma

Answer (score 0):

To install BeautifulSoup in python3 use:

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

Then to import it try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

also it's a good idea to use virtual environments when working on large projects or if you'll be using similar configurations in multiple projects, check this out if you are interested.
[virtual env](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

Comment: pip3 command is not working .. this is also showing  error that

Comment: /usr/bin/python3: No module named pip

Comment: no .your code didn't worked as pip3 don't exist but i found the right code after a lengthy research on this 'apt-get install pip3-bs4' this comand solved the issue,